# Assign classes conditionally using ngclass in angular2?

Tags: angular

I need to change the class depends on value in angular2

```
<p class="pull-right" [ngClass]="">Status: {{payment.status}}</p>
```

For example:

If the status is failed. I need to add class "Fail". If the status is success, I need to change the class as "Success". How do i do this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign class as below as per your status field :

```
<p class="pull-right" [ngClass]="{ 'failed' : payment.status === 'failed', 'success' : payment.status === 'success'}">Status: {{payment.status}}</p>
```